# Linear space transform transformation based on covariance?

Tags: geometry, nonlinear-optimization, covariance

I have a linear space of n dimensions with non-overlapping groups characterized by different variation (different covariance matrices). Is there a way to deform non-linearly the space according to an optimization criterion in order to get a new, non-linear space where the variation of these group would be isotropic?

[Here is a visual description of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zmbzs.jpg)

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: This looks like a question about deforming metric tensors: your covariance matrix acts like the metric at a point. Then you're asking about some sort of global diffeomorphism between $(\mathbb{R}^n,g)$ and $(\mathbb{R}^n,\delta)$. I suspect such a thing is not possible in general due to curvature doing inconvenient things (unless it's zero, of course).